# How to bind two properties of two classes together

Tags: c#, properties, bind

How to define a mirror property to separate class with equal value?
I have a class like this:

```
public abstract class Car
{
    public Point3D Location { get; set; }
}
```

And another class like this:

```
class Motion
{
    public Point3D Location {get; set;}
    public Motion(Point3D location)
    {
        Location  = location;
    }
}
```

I want to Motion.Location be updated when Car.Location changed. This is done until Car.Location don't be renewed.

```
    car1.Location=new Point3D();
```

After that this two properties separated.
So what can I do to guarantee Motion.Location value is same the Car.Location value.

Comment: Not possible, you can't create an instance of `Car` to begin with. It's an abstract class. It sounds like you want two static classes, if you have more than one `Motion` objects or `Car` objects how do you know which `Motion` object to update when any particular `Car.Location` gets changed?

Comment: @tnw Nowhere in the question do I see OP trying to construct an instance of Car. (i.e. Car car1=new Honda(); car1.Location = new Point3D(); /*is valid code*/)

Comment: It's not matter. Suppose car1 is an instance of derived class of Car our suppose Car is't abstract.

Comment: @Nasser Ah yeah that's the clarification I needed, it isn't clear that there's a *derived* class we're working with here rather than `Car` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you could really do is to declare an event at the object level to get notified when the property changes.  But you'd have to add a backend property for `Location` so you can fire an event.

```
public abstract class Car
{
   private Point3D _loc;
   public event System.EventHandler LocationChanged;
   public Point3D Location 
   { 
      get{
          return _loc;
      }
     set; {
       _loc = value;
       if ( LocationChanged != null )
       {
          LocationChanged( this, new EventArgs() );
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes don't have values.  Instances of classes have values.  You aren't creating instances of Car or Motion here so there's really nothing to bind.  If you *had* instances, you could have the setter of car.location update the location value of the motion instance (tho it's not clear from your code where that instance would come from)